# Regex to validate URL path in Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I would like to validate a URL path to make sure it doesn't include things like back-to-back `?`'s, `&`'s, `=`'s or `-`'s. The path should only include a-z, A-Z, 0-9, ?, -, &, and =.

For for example, these should pass:

```
item/643fe4ac-e87d-4b71-8fd1-522154f933c2/okay
person/adam?height=23&favcolor=blue
city/building/916fe4ac-e87d-4b71-8fd1-522154f933r5
```

While these should fail:

```
item/643fe4ac--e87d-4b71-8fd1---522154f933c2/okay
person/adam??height=23&favcolor=blue
city/@/916fe4ac-e87d-4b71-8fd1-522154f933r5
```

Solutions I've looked at online don't seem to work when I try them out on https://regexr.com/ (for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469882/validate-the-path-of-an-url)) or they are built for a non-dynamic url path or for specific situations (i.e. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713655/regular-expression-to-match-on-any-url-parameter-value-perl-syntax) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227408/regex-to-match-url-with-specific-query-string-param)).

I've tried building one from scratch, but I'm very inexperienced with Regex, so I managed to get a starting point of `[a-zA-Z0-9/]*` which basically matches anything except spaces, but needs A LOT of work to get to what I want.

Comment: Please don't dump "write regex for me" coding assignments here.

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: You are going to get a lot of downvotes if you don't post what you've tried, what you're getting as a result, and why it's not working: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you are using a character class. You can use a character class that allows your non-allowed dup characters:

```
[-\/?&]
```

then capture that and use the back reference, in this way you will know a non-allowed dup character occurred.

```
([-\/?&])\1
```

You then can add a negated character class to see if a non-allowed character is present:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\/&=?-]
```

These two expressions can be put together:

```
(?:([-\/?&])\1|[^A-Za-z0-9\/&=?-])
```

and then if you have a match the string is invalid.

https://regex101.com/r/zPIObe/3/